# no .fls file generated

Tags: auxiliary-files

I currently use pdflatex under texmaker and I don't see a .fls file when compiling anyone know how to fix this?

p.s. if anyone knows a simple way to find unused images I would also be interested.

Comment: tex does not write fls files by default you need to supply the `--recorder` option, your editor will have a configuration somewhere to specify the options used for each menu command.

Comment: a simple way to find the unused images would be to delete them all, run latex, then just put back the ones for which missing file errors were given